# How to get 3D coordinates from depth maps

Tags: 3d, pytorch, depth-testing

I can get the depth map from depth estimation which uses supervised or unsupervised learning, but here is an obstacle that I want to get 3D coordinates from depth maps. If anyone can provide some suggestions.

Comment: Do you have access to the camera's intrinsics?

Comment: I can get the intrinsics

Comment: Given `D` the 2D depth map , `K^-1` the inverse of the camera intrinsics matrix, and `p` the 2D pixel coordinates of the image. The transformation pipeline is `D*K^-1*p`. Have you heard about such transformation before?

Comment: Yes, I have heard about this transformation, change the camera world to the true world

Comment: This transformation unprojects the pixel elements to 3D view using the camera intrinsics matrix `K`, and your depth map `D` which removes ambiguity in the problem. I've you had a go at it? I suggest you try on paper and see how you can unproject a 2D point from image coordinate to camera view using the transform above. Then I can help with the implementation details.

Comment: Any solution to this?